# Cannot drag a slider in Safari browser with selenium or javascript

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Unable to drag a slider from a java function in Safari browser automated session.
Tried using the following selenium and javascript options

**Selenium methods**

For all following cases:

builder is an instance of org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions class

sliderElement is an instance of org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

shift is the calculated position where I want the slider to be positioned after the action

1. `builder.dragAndDropBy(sliderElement, shift, 0).release().build().perform();`

This mechanism for dragging slider is working for other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and
Edge. It didn't perform any action in Safari browser.

2. `builder.moveToElement(sliderElement, shift, 0).click().build().perform()`

This mechanism for dragging slider is working for other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and
Edge. It didn't perform any action in Safari browser.

3. `builder.clickAndHold(sliderElement).moveByOffset(shift, 0).release().perform();`

It didn't perform any action in Safari browser.

**Javascript methods**

1. `document.getElementById("seek-bar").value = xxx`

This mechanism for dragging slider is working for other browsers like Chrome, Firefox and
Edge. It didn't perform any action in Safari browser.

2. `executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", sliderElement );`

This didn't perform any action in safari browser; but this method is used to click on other elements in safari browser

3.

```
function mouseEvent(type, sx, sy, cx, cy) {
    var evt
    var e = {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: type != 'mousemove',
        view: window,
        detail: 0,
        screenX: sx,
        screenY: sy,
        clientX: cx,
        clientY: cy,
        ctrlKey: false,
        altKey: false,
        shiftKey: false,
        metaKey: false,
        button: 0,
        relatedTarget: undefined,
    }
    if (typeof document.createEvent == 'function') {
        evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
        evt.initMouseEvent(
            type,
            e.bubbles,
            e.cancelable,
            e.view,
            e.detail,
            e.screenX,
            e.screenY,
            e.clientX,
            e.clientY,
            e.ctrlKey,
            e.altKey,
            e.shiftKey,
            e.metaKey,
            e.button,
            document.body.parentNode
        )
    } else if (document.createEventObject) {
         evt = document.createEventObject()
         for (prop in e) {
               evt[prop] = e[prop]
         }
         evt.button =
         {
              0: 1,
              1: 4,
              2: 2,
         }[evt.button] || evt.button
     }
    return evt
}


function dispatchEvent(el, evt) {
    if (el.dispatchEvent) {
        el.dispatchEvent(evt)
    } else if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('on' + type, evt)
    }
    return evt
}


var test = document.getElementById("vol")
var top = test.offsetTop + window.screenY + 7;
var left = test.offsetLeft + window.screenX + 40;
var evt = mouseEvent("click", left, top, test.offsetLeft + 10, test.offsetTop + 7);
dispatchEvent(test, evt);
```

This also didn't perform any action in safari browser.

Safari Version: 14.1.1

MAC OS Version: 11.4 Big Sur

I have tried these methods using the following page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html onclick="onCLick()">
<html>
<body>

<h1>Display a Range Field</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onCLick(event){
    console.log("clicked")
    var x = event.clientX
    var y = event.clientY
    console.log(x + " " + y);
  }
  function mouseEvent(type, sx, sy, cx, cy) {
  var evt
  var e = {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: type != 'mousemove',
    view: window,
    detail: 0,
    screenX: sx,
    screenY: sy,
    clientX: cx,
    clientY: cy,
    ctrlKey: false,
    altKey: false,
    shiftKey: false,
    metaKey: false,
    button: 0,
    relatedTarget: undefined,
  }
  if (typeof document.createEvent == 'function') {
    evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
    evt.initMouseEvent(
      type,
      e.bubbles,
      e.cancelable,
      e.view,
      e.detail,
      e.screenX,
      e.screenY,
      e.clientX,
      e.clientY,
      e.ctrlKey,
      e.altKey,
      e.shiftKey,
      e.metaKey,
      e.button,
      document.body.parentNode
    )
  } else if (document.createEventObject) {
    evt = document.createEventObject()
    for (prop in e) {
      evt[prop] = e[prop]
    }
    evt.button =
      {
        0: 1,
        1: 4,
        2: 2,
      }[evt.button] || evt.button
  }
  return evt
}
function dispatchEvent(el, evt) {
  if (el.dispatchEvent) {
    el.dispatchEvent(evt)
  } else if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + type, evt)
  }
  return evt
}
document.addEventListener("click", onCLick);
</script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="vol">Volume (between 0 and 50):</label>
  <input type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="100" onclick="onCLick()">
  <input id="sub" type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good question - you've had a great go at it.  Any chance you can share a URL so i can try a few things?  or are you aware of a public site in which you experience the same issue?  - anything beyond what you've tried will be a bit of a guess and i'd rather have a go before posting responses

Comment: This URL can be used to launch a page with a slider - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range 
On running the code snippet in question the same page is locally generated,  have tried all the methods on it.

Comment: Turns out i no longer have access to safari in a mac. We'll have to debug this across a few comments!  ... Lets make sure JS is an option. In safari, when then page is open can you query the seek bar's value with JS?  - manually click somewhere in the middle of the slider, open devtools and run `document.getElementById("seek-bar").value`  do you get a value output?  - point of that is the ensure that JS is being run against your expected element

Comment: After that - one approach you've not tried is phsyical key presses from selenium  - activate the control then press right on the keybaord... such as: `sliderElement.click(); sliderElement.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);`   - you may need to put a loop around the arrow_right - it moves 1 value per keypress

Comment: document.getElementById("seek-bar").value returns a numeric value like "20", 


sliderElement.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT) this worked, and it moved the slider by 5 seconds in forward direction, putting this in a loop is definitely a possibility, but I was looking for something that would shift the slider directly to a point on the seek-bar

Comment: You've got a solution: You can get the .value to know where you are and you can change the value with keys. I get it's from from ideal but everything else you said you tried did not work. This might your only resort.  Sorry buddy but I don't have the hardware or software to support you further.

Comment: Only thing you pretty much said you tried, which would be the go-to solution would be this `executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value=25;", sliderElement );`  - that's a hardcoded value that goes the 25. You can param that further.